# Show .txt file on a Hyperlink using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, web

I want to show a text file online as a description when users click on a link, and I want it to be a text file, not the html page. I want it just like this link https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt.
I have uploaded the .txt file and it opens when the user clicks hyperlink, but contents of that .txt file are not shown....
Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: Hareesh this is the link to my dummy text file.....text is not visible in that...
http://bahriacarrental.uphero.com/sanaa.txt

Answer (score 0):

Its about File-Permissions, you have to set them to **Public & Read**
This solution is provided to "*Online Sites*" only. 
**(Not for XAMPP)**

1. Go to Your Admin Panel
2. Go to Media
3. Upload your Textfile to your Webserver
4. Browse your Textfile (**via FTP-Client**) and make a RightClick
5. Set CHMOD to 744. (read)(This are File-Permissions)
6. Open the File in your Browser and it should appear normally.

I've tested it 5 Minutes ago, it should work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marek....I have changed the CHMOD code to 744 via FTP-Client, but the text in that .txt file is still not visible....:(

Comment: What was the Code before u have changed it? 600?

Comment: Make sure Wordpress does not split ur Uploads in seperate folders like per year, per month.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the link using Developer Tools (on Chrome) or using Firebug (on Firefox), you'll know that the file is missing. You have not uploaded the file to that location.

Comment: Its in the directory....I have checked it via FileZilla (FTP Client). If it is not there then it must show an error message of "404 Page Not Found"...